# trigger button click when hitting ENTER?

Tags: c#, forms, button, textbox

I have successfully assigned the ENTER key to trigger the button1 click event. When i hit ENTER it should open the form "Startmenu". However it does this TWICE. Not once only. I can't quite find the problem in my code, can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
public Login()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    this.textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (somethingsomething == true)
    {
        Startmenu sm = new Startmenu();
        sm.Show();
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("something");
    }    

}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in button1_Click_1 and check the callstack to see 
who is triggering the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1_Click_1.Click(sender,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. With or without editing this line "this.textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);" to match.

Comment: I get the following error: 
The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= ?

Comment: ohh sorry in your case it should be button1_Click_1 not button1_Click , im sorry , please check my edited answer now it works perfectly.

Comment: Copied that right in. Now it says: PresentationTier_Applikation.Login.button1_Click_1(object, System.EventArgs)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: you dont need to have the KeyPress Event now you just edit the same code whatever you posted in question just replace only textBox1_KeyDown() function

Comment: Yep, i did that. Replaced the original with yours.

Comment: No sorry. Still same error as before. I replaced my own textbox1_KeyDown() function with yours..

Comment: same error means PresentationTier_Applikation.Login.button1_Click_1(object, System.EventArgs)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context?